# How can I use firefox-29.0.tar.bz2

Tags: updates, firefox

I have downloaded "firefox-29.0.tar.bz2" to update my firefox. How do I use this file to update firefox?

Comment: "how to use this to update firefox ?" you do not. This does not update; It will overwrite your current firefox.

Comment: And besides using a tar why not the debian installer? saves you a lot of trouble...

Comment: @DavidFoerster Agreed. that's a better dupe choice for this. VTR.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything to update Firefox to Firefox 29. Firefox 29 is already available from your normal software updates. Just open the Software Updater and you will be asked if you want to get the update.

Answer (score 2):

First, extract the package,

```
tar -xjf firefox-29.0.tar.bz2
```

Then replace the older firefox,

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/firefox     (remove the folder, might be named differently)
sudo mv firefox /opt/firefox (mv to where old folder was)
```

Then fix the symbolic links,

```
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

The easiest way, though, is just

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```